# Editing the master page

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, design, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to edit the master page and I have downloaded a copy of the master page.

When I open it in visual studio it shows me an error saying:

> Error Creating Control - SPHtmlTag
>   Unknown server tag 'SharePoint:SPHtmlTag'

Here is the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are editing .master version of master page. Please make changes to master page using .html file.

.Master file will be updated automatically.

Comment: where do i find the .html file of master page?